# Javascript disabled after page is resized/scaled to a device?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

This is a rather odd question, particularly hard to search, as I'm not quite sure what's happening. I've designed a page with bootstrap and prepared it to scale accross many devices using the lg, md and sm prefixes and all that jazz.

The issue happens when I try to scale it in small screen sizes. The buttons, usually are list items, links and buttons. I have a section of tabs as well.
When they scale to a smaller screen they simply stop working, the tabs won't change... etc...

Comment: yes its odd question..

Comment: And what exactly is your odd question ?

Comment: We need an example of reproduced issue.

Comment: I'm not sure how to reproduce this @halfzebra, should I record a video of it happening? I basically resize the window and *poof* the tabs stop working.

Comment: @Thaenor video has no informative value for developers, we need the code to reproduce the issue. Consider using code snippets or [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: It's a huge batch of code... and I can't pinpoint the precise issue... since there's no errors or anything. I'll try to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, turns out I had the footer covering the rest of the page... that's why I couldn't click anywhere except the nav...

When in doubt alway use the inspect element... I guess that's the lesson to take away from this.